# Make mandatory fields only when moving from specific field

Tags: servicenow

Make mandatory fields only when moving from specific field - for ex. `State` from `Implement` to `Review`.

Can I do that through UI Polices?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with [Client scripts](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/script/client-scripts/concept/client-scripts.html) of ServiceNow.

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) { 
     if (newValue == "review" && oldValue == "implement")
     g_form.setMandatory("your_field", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the change state model, the only transition available for Implement State is to move towards the Review State. So you can reach Review only through a direct pass from Implement state.

So Yes this is possible via a UI Policy.

You can have a UI Policy condition that says State is Review 
Add your required UI policy actions to make the fields Mandatory=true